# How do I print method of interface

Tags: java

How can I print connect method of interface?
I'd like to modify the mains only by minimizing the class modification.

if i use arr[0].connect();
Error :
The method connect() is undefined for the type Device

```
public class main{

    private static Device arr[];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        init();
        arr[0].print();
        arr[1].print();

    }

    public static void init() {
        arr = new Device[2];
        arr[0] = new Printer();
        arr[1] = new UsbMem();
    }

}

public interface Connectable {
    public static final String name = ":USB";
    public abstract void connect();
}

public abstract class Device {
    public abstract void print();
}

public class Printer extends Device implements Connectable {

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("It's a printer");
    }

    public void connect() {
        System.out.println(name + "connect with printer");
    }
}

public class UsbMem extends Device implements Connectable {

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("USB memory");
    }

    public void connect() {
        System.out.println(name + "connect with usb memory");
    }
}
```

It's a printer.
:USB connect with printer
USB memory
:USB connect with usb memory

Comment: `((Connectable) arr[0]).connect()`. This will lead to a `ClassCastException` if there ever will be a `Device` that is not implementing `Connectable`, so you might do a `x instanceof Connectable` check first.

Comment: @Lothar If you have an answer to the question, please post it as an answer or upvote the question of user1717259, if you think this should be the correct one.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re While writing the comment somebody provided the same thing as answer already, so I don't see much benefit "for the world" if I add my own response to this question.

Comment: @Lothar, sure thing. But what you actually did was providing an answer within a comment. If someone answered then, while you're typing, why keeping it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Device` needs to implement `Connectable`.

```
public class Main {

    private static Device arr[];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        init();
        arr[0].print();
        arr[1].print();
    }

    public static void init() {
        arr = new Device[2];
        arr[0] = new Printer();
        arr[1] = new UsbMem();
    }
}

public interface Connectable {
    public static final String name = ":USB";
    public abstract void connect();
}

public abstract class Device implements Connectable {
    public abstract void print();
}

public class Printer extends Device {

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("It's a printer");
    }

    public void connect() {
        System.out.println(name + "connect with printer");
    }
}

public class UsbMem extends Device {

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("USB memory");
    }

    public void connect() {
        System.out.println(name + "connect with usb memory");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the object to a Connectable

`((Connectable)arr[0]).connect()`

Comment: While that's correct, it may lead to a `ClassCastException` if the code isn't written properly.